# Data on recycleview item is not correct when scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**My adapter code:**

```
public class BrandAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BrandAdapter.BrandViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = BrandAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<BrandItem> brands;

    private Context context;

    public BrandAdapter(Context context, List<BrandItem> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.brands = data;
    }

    public void setData(List<BrandItem> dataDownload) {
        this.brands = dataDownload;
    }


    @Override
    public BrandViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_brand, null);

        BrandViewHolder holder = new BrandViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BrandViewHolder holder, int position) {
        BrandItem brandItem = brands.get(position);
        String name = brandItem.getName();
        int count = brandItem.getCountArticles();

        holder.tvName.setText(name);
        if (count > 0) {
            holder.tvCount.setText("" + count);
        } else {
            holder.tvCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return brands.size();
    }

    public static class BrandViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvCount;

        public BrandViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand_name);
            tvCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_count_article);

        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment code :**

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

adapter = new BrandAdapter(getActivity(), brands);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Data for brands is downloaded from server. After downloaded finished, I just set new data for adapter by this code :**

```
brands = downloadedBrands();
adapter.setData(brands);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Everything is Ok when data loaded for first time after the download finish. But when I scroll down the recycleview and scroll up again, data for each item is wrong now, all textview **tvCount** is gone. I do not know why.

Is there any problem from my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make tvCount visible when setting a non-zero count.

```
if (count > 0) {
        holder.tvCount.setText("" + count);
        holder.tvCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.tvCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Greenrobo's answer is correct but here is an explanation as to WHY you are having this issue.

You are assuming that your view is always set to the default values in your `onBindViewHolder` method.

The `RecyclerView` re-uses views that have scrolled off screen and therefore the view you are binding to may have already been previously used (and changed).

You `onBindViewHolder` method should always set EVERYTHING up. i.e all views reset to the exact values you want and do not assume that because you default an item to visible, it will always be so.

Comment: I got it, your explain is exactly. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You told that if count is less than 0, hide the view. What if count is greater than zero ? You are not making the view visible again. So simply make the below changes in your if condition:

```
if (count > 0) {
        holder.tvCount.setText("" + count);
        holder.tvCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
} else {
        holder.tvCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explain. your answer is the same with @greenrobo. It work well.